# Переделать ArrayList в обычный массив String[]

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Есть `ArrayList<String>` который автоматически заполняется данными(ссылками). Хочу преобразовать его в простой `String[]` командой:

```
public static ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] url = new String[linkList.size()]; // ошибка
url = linkList.toArray(url);
```

Но Eсlipse ругается на  **;** причем вне зависимости от того как я пытаюсь преобразовать, в этом случае тоже будет ошибка:

```
String[] url = {}; // ошибка
url = linkList.toArray(new String[linkList.size()]);
```

В этом варианте нет ошибки:

```
String[] url = linkList.toArray(new String[linkList.size()]);
```

Но если попытаться вывести на консоль, то вместо данных я получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Ljava.lang.String;@45ds364

А вот такой вариант крашит программу:

```
lk.setText("Ссылка: " +url[2]);
```

Такой нормально покажет ссылку:

```
lk.setText("Ссылка: " +linkList.get(2));
```

Соответственно вопрос в чем может быть ошибка и  как лучше преобразовать `ArrayList` в обычный массив.

Comment: Нижеследующий фрагмент нормально компилится. Может вы что-то недоговариваете?

    ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] url = new String[linkList.size()];
    url = linkList.toArray(url);

> Но если попытаться вывести на консоль, то вместо данных я получаю вот такую ошибку:
> 
> `Ljava.lang.String;@45ds364`

Это не ошибка, это нормальное поведение. Метод `toString()` у массивов не переопределен. если хотите получить строковое представление массива используйте `Arrays.deepToString(myArray)`

> `String[] url = {}; // ошибка`

такого синтаксиса в Java нет вовсе.

Comment: > А вот такой вариант крашит программу:
>
> lk.setText("Ссылка: " +url[2]);

Скиньте сюда сообщение об ошибке и стэктрейс, если несложно.

Comment: 02-07 14:33:55.393: E/AndroidRuntime(377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 14:33:55.393: E/AndroidRuntime(377): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Насколько я понимаю массив просто пуст и при попытке обратиться к несуществующими значению выскакивает ошибка, так как исключения не прописаны. Но если я прав, почему строковый массив пуст тогда как с динамическим все нормально.

Comment: Вообще наполнение массива идет в отдельном потоке, если преобразовывать внутри этого потока в onPostExecute то показывает последнюю ссылку. В остальных случаях та ошибка, что выше.

Comment: Спасибо, сумел разобраться. Нужно было правильно расположить присваивание внутри отдельного потока.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Чтобы вывести массив, необходимо использовать `Arrays.toString()`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Неправда, `toArray(T[])` [возвращает](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) `T[]`, а не `Object[]`, так что преобразование к `String[]` не нужно.

Comment: Да, правда перепутал, приведение нужно было бы в этом случае: `public static String[] qq(List list){
        String[] arr = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        return arr;
    }`

Comment: Ответ поправил.

Answer (score 1):

(Щас меня заминусят, прям чувствую)

Попробуйте конвертировать вот так:

```
String[] output = new String[array.size()];
for (int i = 0; i != array.size(); i++) {
    output[i] = array.get(i);
}
```

Мне этот способ не один раз помог.

Comment: Обычно и

    String[] url = linkList.toArray(new String[linkList.size()]);

проблем не вызывает.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет частично помог.