# Как переместить элементы ресурсов из string массива в int массив

Tags: java, android

У меня есть int массив который хранит нужные мне элементы и у меня есть ArrayList типа String который хранит подобные элементы.
Как мне передавать эти элементы в int массив? По поводу первого массива, как я понимаю хранить он эти значения может, так как это классифицируется как id ресурса, как мне узнать эти id или есть другое решение?

Comment: id ресурса – это константы, которые генерируются автоматически. Доступ к ним вы получаете через класс R. Например, R.drawable.russia

Comment: @КириллМалышев это понятно, но проблемы не решает

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что вам нужно получить доступ к ресурсам по такой строке "R.drawable.russia"? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4427608/7485582

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295245/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-arraylist-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-string вот твой ответ

Comment: Какой смысл делать такие строки? Делайте ArrayList<Integer> и просто уберите из кода кавычки. Числа будут правильные если вы именно ссылаетесь на R класс, а не используете значения, которые увидели в сгенерированном файле